# * character in tag filter on Review removes the bolding

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, tag-filters

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/)
2. Click `filter`
3. Type `win` - observe the bold
4. Append a `*`, or add one anywhere - observe the plain text

[image: a]

[image: d]

[image: b]

Is this a bug?

Also, I don't know why a ream of commas matches stuff:

[image: c]

Comment: Commas aren't valid in tags, so they probably just get stripped. The system probably thinks you've entered an empty string and is just displaying the top six tags on the site. If you go to the [tags page](http://stackoverflow.com) and enter a bunch of commas, you get the full list like nothing is there. This goes for *any* invalid character, even the asterisk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asterisks and commas aren't valid characters in tags, so the server just ignores them when returning the tag search results. The client-side behavior is undefined.